# How to count the number of values in a discrete function?

Tags: list-manipulation, functions

I have a discrete function of an integer variable $n$ defined like this :

```
theta[n_] := 
 {0.0902266, 0.0889051, 0.0869336, 0.0840726, 0.0838656, 
  0.0931356, 0.0958106, 0.0931356, 0.0838666, 0.0840726, 0.0869326, 
 -0.0889051, 0.0902266, 0.0911066, 0.0917297, 0.0922456, 0.0927188, 
  0.0930936, 0.0932416, 0.0930936, -0.0927186, 0.0922446, 0.0917296, 
  0.0911066, 0.0869336, 0.0911066, 0.0931356, 0.0869336, -0.0931356,  
  0.0911066, -0.0872142, 0.0872142, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.0872142,
  0.0911066, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.00315, -0.00315}[[n]]
```

This function is defined so that I get these outputs :

```
theta[1] = 0.0902266
theta[2] = 0.0889051
...
theta[40] = -0.00315
```

I need to define a *constant* which is the total number of elements in the previous list.  In the example above, there are $40$ elements inside the list, so that constant should be equal to $40$.

Apparently, I can't apply the command `Lenght` on the function above, in *Mathematica*.  So how can I count the total number of outputs from that function ?

The reason I need this is that I may have to change the number of items inside that discrete function.

Any idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oh well, the solution to my problem is trivial.  I simply have to change the definition of my theta function, like this :

```
Angles := {0.0902266, 0.0889051, 0.0869336, 0.0840726, 0.0838656, ...}

theta[n_] := Angles[[n]]
```

Then I can use the length command on the Angles :

```
Nangles = Length[Angles];
```

Answer (score 6):

You can take advantage of how the rules associated with `theta` are stored behind the scenes by doing

```
Length @ DownValues[theta][[1, 2, 1]]
(* 40 *)
```

This isn't robust, however. In the sense that if you have defined beforehand `theta[10] = 5`, for instance, then it won't find the right `DownValue`.

Alternatively, you can build the checking into the function:

```
Clear[theta, thetaHeld]
theta[n_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= n <= Length@thetaHeld[n][[1, 1]]] := ReleaseHold[thetaHeld[n]]
thetaHeld[n_] := Hold[
  List[0.0902266, 0.0889051, 0.0869336, 0.0840726, 0.0838656
   , 0.0931356, 0.0958106, 0.0931356, 0.0838666, 0.0840726
   , 0.0869326, -0.0889051, 0.0902266, 0.0911066, 0.0917297
   , 0.0922456,0.0927188, 0.0930936, 0.0932416, 0.0930936
   , -0.0927186, 0.0922446, 0.0917296, 0.0911066, 0.0869336
   , 0.0911066, 0.0931356, 0.0869336, -0.0931356, 0.0911066
   , -0.0872142, 0.0872142, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.0872142
   , 0.0911066, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.00315, -0.00315][[n]]]
```

This even works if the list has been defined before:

```
list = {0.0902266, 0.0889051, 0.0869336, 0.0840726, 0.0838656
   , 0.0931356, 0.0958106, 0.0931356, 0.0838666, 0.0840726
   , 0.0869326, -0.0889051, 0.0902266, 0.0911066, 0.0917297
   , 0.0922456,0.0927188, 0.0930936, 0.0932416, 0.0930936
   , -0.0927186, 0.0922446, 0.0917296, 0.0911066, 0.0869336
   , 0.0911066, 0.0931356, 0.0869336, -0.0931356, 0.0911066
   , -0.0872142, 0.0872142, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.0872142
   , 0.0911066, 0.001, 0.0911066, 0.00315, -0.00315};


Clear[theta, thetaHeld]
theta[n_?IntegerQ /; 1 <= n <= Length@thetaHeld[n][[1, 1]]] := ReleaseHold[thetaHeld[n]]
thetaHeld[n_] := Hold[list[[n]]]
```

Then:

```
theta[4]
(* 0.0840726 *)
```

and

```
theta[41]
(* *)
```